# Is "none" when used alone without antecedent singular or plural (for context, I'm talking about people): "None [are/is] here"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

I know that *"none of [...]"* can be both singular or plural, but when I use it **alone in a sentence**, without the *"of"* and without any other nouns, can it be both singular and plural or does it depend on the context?

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/a/456280/15299.

Comment: Yes, it normally functions as determiner in singular or plural fused-head NPs: "Ed had plenty of money, but Kim had none" ~ "Ted made many mistakes but Gill made none".

Comment: It doesn't need an antecedent: "Ed has a good time, but none of my friends turned up".

Comment: @BillJ: In "none of my friends," *friends* is the antecedent (okay, technically it's a postcedent and not an antecedent, but in any case the OP specifically excludes the *none of the ...* construction in his question). As far as I can tell, *none* always needs an antecedent or a postcedent.

Answer (score 2):

'None' is a contraction of 'not one'. It can also mean 'no one', 'nobody', 'to no extent', or 'not any'. It can therefore take on both a singular and a plural verb, **depending, indeed, on the context**.

- No one is here/nobody is here/none is here.

- I invited five of my friends. *None were here*.
- They were at my place, eating all my bread. *None is left*.

But also consider these examples from [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/none/):

- None of the books is worth reading.
- None of the books are worth reading.

As is stated there, "*both are correct, and a person could choose to use either. The second, though, sounds more natural to many English speakers, as the context concerns multiple books*".

Answer (score 2):

We don't generally use *none* without some antecedent. It almost always has an antecedent, although possibly it's in a previous sentence. If you want to use *none* without an antecedent, you should instead use *nothing*, *nobody*, or *no one*.

When you use *none*, the verb should agree with the antecedent, as Joachim's answer says.

> Usually, there are a lot of people outside that restaurant, waiting for a table. But yesterday, none were.

(Because you expect a lot of people, *was* sounds quite strange to me in this sentence.)

> I wanted to read a book by Robert Bookwriter. However, none were/was in the library.

(Because you only want to read one book, both *were* and *was* sound acceptable to me. My impression is that *were* is more common.)

> There was a fire in the post office, and some of the mail was singed. However, none was destroyed.

(Because *mail* is an uncountable noun, you need to use *was* here.)